# WPF Control binding does not always update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a button whose `IsEnabled` property is bound within my view model to a value indicating whether or not the data in the current view has been modified. This binding has been working fine so far until I'd tried adding Drag/Drop functionality to an ItemsControl within the view.

The Drag/Drop function is working fine and does everything it's supposed to. When it's completed any data manipulation it needs to, it sets the View Model's `IsModified` property to `true`. I've verified that the value is *actually* set to `true`.

**The problem** I'm having is that, when the `IsModified` property is changed from within my `Drop` method, the button's `IsEnabled` property isn't updating; when `IsModified` is set to `true` during the drag/drop operation, the button remains disabled. If I click the button, it suddenly updates and becomes enabled, requiring me to press the button a second time to actually do as it's intended.

The `Drop` method is being called on the `Drop` event on the ItemsControl item. Is this being called from another thread or something that is not informing the UI of the property change? I've tried finding supporting docs, but am having a bit of trouble.

Once again, setting the `IsModified` property continues to work under any other circumstances and updates the UI properly.

The code in question is fairly simple.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <EventSetter Event="DragEnter" Handler="IcFields_DragEnter"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="IcFields_Drop"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

...
...
...

<Button Margin="5" Padding="10,0,10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsModified}"
    Command="{Binding SaveChangesCommand}">Save Changes</Button>
```

where the `IcFields_Drop` handler allows the changes to be made to the model and, in the end, sets `IsModified` to `true`.

Edit:

Here's an abbreviated example of the implementation. Use the XAML above as the XAML for this example.

C# - Code-Behind

```
private void IcFields_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.Drop();   
}
```

C# - View Model

```
private bool isModified;
public bool IsModified
{
    get { return isModified; }
    set { SetProperty(ref isModified, value); }
}

public void Drop()
{
    //PSEUDO: Do some drag/drop logic for the items attached to the ItemsControl.
    ...
    ...

    IsModified = true;
}
```

Comment: Try this `IsEnabled="{Binding IsModified, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: @ikerbera Unfortunately, didn't do the trick.

Comment: `IsEnabled="{Binding IsModified, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}, Mode=OneWay"`. I usually use `Mode=TwoWay`, but in this case it feels a bit of overkill. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @ikerbera `Mode=TwoWay` is nonsense since the control never actively updates its IsEnabled property, hence there is no binding direction from target to source. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is also pointless, because it only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Does your view model (since the code is not shown) implement inotifypropertychanged?

Comment: @KevinCook Yes, it does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. As mentioned, the bound property works as intended except in the case of being altered during a `Drop` event.

Comment: Without seeing what your viewmodel is doing, it's hard to diagnose anything.  Is there any threading involved in the code?  Are you mixing code behind and mvvm?

Comment: @KevinCook For all intents and purposes, we can say that all the view model does during a `Drop` event is set `IsModified = true` and then return. In this context, that's all it really needs to do.

Comment: Is it possible to share a small working example. This kind of weird problems are hard to solve without being able to reproduce.

Comment: @Mertus I've added a simplified example of what I'm doing, adding to the XAML example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the `IsEnabled` property, you should return a `bool` from the `CanExecute` method of your command to indicate whether the `Button` should be enabled. You would then call a method that raises the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the command in your `Drop()` method.

Most `ICommand` implementations include a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method or similar that you can call to refresh the status of the command:

```
public void Drop()
{
    ...
    SaveChangesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Comment: That's a great point. I have `IsEnabled` bound when I don't really need it to be, so I can at least discard that. I don't currently have a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method in my implementation, so I will see about adding one. For the time being, though, it looks like something is catching at the end of my DragDrop; it does not update `IsEnabled` until **anywhere** on the screen is clicked. Looking into it.

Comment: @pseudorian: You could take a look at how it is implemented in [MvvmLight](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/1f67dfbcfb776b785727c1505566dc5f7c72a891/V3/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommand.cs) for example.

Comment: This did work for me, thank you! I am still not sure why only the `Drop` event is causing this issue, so I'm going to continue looking into it, but, at the very least, it works and I have a slightly better `ICommand` implementation to work with.